# Is it always true that if $a^2=b$ then $a=\pm\sqrt{b}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

Is it always true that if $a^2=b$ then $a=\pm\sqrt{b}$ ? I've seen it stated that if $x^2=k$ then $x=\pm\sqrt{k}$ where k is real, but have not seen the more general case, so I'm wondering if there is a reason why not.
If this is not true generally, what are some counter examples that could be shown on an Algebra 1 level?

Edit: A better statement of my original question might be this...

> It appears that "if $a=b$ then $a+c=b+c$" is universally true
> regardless of context. Are there contexts in which $a^2=b$ could not
> be equivalently written as $a=\pm\sqrt{b}$ ? Would any such context be
> understandable on an Algebra 1 level? Perhaps where still with $a$ and
> $b$ limited as either complex numbers or expressions with complex
> coefficients.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you familiar with the complex number system? This is the set of numbers of the form $x+yi$, where $i^2=-1$. In this number system, every number other than $0$ has two different square roots.

Comment: I am. I guess I was also wondering about when $a$ and $b$ are expressions. Maybe for whatever reason there are cases when it doesn't hold then? I suppose if it holds for all complex numbers, then it would have to hold for all expressions as well.

Comment: Your emphasis on "expressions" is not clear. Equations like $a^2=b$ are usually understood by saying exactly what number system $a$ and $b$ are allowed to vary over, for example: "Given a real number $b$, solve $a^2=b$ for all solutions $a$ in the real numbers"; or one could replace "real" with "complex" in that sentence.

Comment: Every complex number has two square roots (apart from $0$). And if $a$ and $b$ are algebraic expressions, then since those algebraic expressions *represent* arbitrary numbers, yes, they also have two square roots.

Comment: Every equation involving "expressions" is a shorthand for a statement about numbers. For example, $(x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1$ means "if $x$ is any real number, then $(x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1$", so $(5+1)^2=5^2+2(5)+1$, and $(\pi + 1)^2=\pi^2+2\pi + 1$, etc. (Incidentally, this equation is also true for complex numbers.)

Comment: @Joe Based on user's answer below, would it be more correct to state that if $a^2=b$ then $a=\pm i \sqrt{-b}$ ?

Comment: @Elem-Teach-w-Bach-n-Math-Ed The standard definition of the square root function $\,\sqrt{\,\cdot\,}\,$ is over non-negative reals. If you want to extend it to $\,\sqrt{z}\,$ where $z \in \mathbb R^-$ or $z \in \mathbb C$ then first thing you must tell is how you define *your* square root function.

Comment: @Elem-Teach-w-Bach-n-Math-Ed: It is best to state the context explicitly. If $a^2=b$, and *$b$ is a non-negative real number*, then $a=\pm\sqrt{b}$. If $a^2=b$, and *$b$ is a negative real number*, then $a=\pm i \sqrt{-b}$.

Comment: @Elem-Teach-w-Bach-n-Math-Ed: Additionally, it is not clear what $\sqrt{x}$ means when $x$ is not a non-negative real number. People often write things like $\sqrt{-1}=i$, but this is misleading. Why should $\sqrt{-1}$ be $i$ rather than $-i$? Note that there is no such thing as "positive" and "negative" complex numbers, so the answer "$i$ is the positive solution to $x^2=-1$" doesn't work.

Comment: @Joe That makes sense. Therefore, there *are* cases where it would be incorrect to rewrite an equation of the form $a^2=b$ as $a=\pm\sqrt{b}$. That's really what I was trying to get at, but having a hard time verbalizing.

Comment: @Elem-Teach-w-Bach-n-Math-Ed: Yes, there are cases where it doesn't make sense to write that. You don't even need a particularly "exotic" example like the quarternions. For example, in the positive integers, the equation $x^2=8$ does not have any solutions, and the symbol $\sqrt{8}$ makes no sense. It is only in the real and complex number systems where the symbol $\sqrt{8}$ is defined. Context matters very much in mathematics.

Comment: @Joe Definitely agree! I guess I was confused why "if $a=b$ then $a+c=b+c$" seems to be universally true regardless of context, but wasn't sure why my statement wasn't often stated as universally true, and in which contexts it wasn't true. Thank you for taking the time to help me gain clarity of thought on this!

Comment: @Elem-Teach-w-Bach-n-Math-Ed: I'm very glad I could help. Actually, for your example $a=b\implies a+c=b+c$, that statement would be true in any number system where addition is defined. This is because $a=b$ means "$a$ and $b$ literally represent exactly the same number, and so they have *identical* properties". Therefore, if $a+c$ equals $x$, then $b+c$ also equals $x$, and vice versa.

Comment: @Elem-Teach-w-Bach-n-Math-Ed: However, there are number systems where $a+b\neq b+a$, for example. These are called "non-abelian groups". Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @Joe Or for example $2+12=2$ in modular arithmetics (mod 12).

Comment: Have you encountered matrices yet? If so, I could give a more "exotic" kind of answer to your question.

Comment: @jasnee I have, and I admit to being intrigued!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In any (commutative) [field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)) a quadratic equation like $x^2 = k$ can have at most $2$ solutions. If the field is the field $\Bbb{R}$ of real numbers, then we know that $x^2 = k$ has no solutions if $k < 0$, $1$ solution if $k = 0$ and $2$ solutions if $k > 0$. In the real numbers, we can also conveniently define $\sqrt{k}$ for $k \ge 0$ to be the non-negative solution of $x^2 = k$, so that the solutions of $x^2 = k$ are indeed $x = \pm \sqrt{k}$.

If we move to the field $\Bbb{C}$ of [complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number), then $x^2 = k$ always has $1$ or $2$ solutions: $1$ if $k = 0$ and $2$ otherwise. In $\Bbb{C}$, we can still think of the solutions as comprising $\pm \sqrt{k}$, but the function $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is trickier to define (there are many possibly definitions, depending on the choice of what is called a [branch cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_point)).

If we carry on with the [Cayley-Dickson construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Dickson_construction) and move to $\Bbb{H}$, the  [quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion), which is a **division ring** (like a field but with a multiplication that is not commutative) then an equation like $x^2 = k$ typically has infinitely many solutions. In $\Bbb{H}$, it doesn't make much sense to try to define $\sqrt{\cdot}$.

I think the above goes beyond Algebra 1, but I hope it is of interest.

Comment: It is of interest! So, in the case of quaternions, would it be incorrect to state that if $a^2=b$ then $a=\pm\sqrt{b}$ ? Or would this still be correct, but defined differently? Or maybe its an invalid statement altogether since $\sqrt$ isn't well defined in quaternions?

Comment: In $\Bbb{H}$, $a^2 = -1$ (for example) has infinitely many solutions, so we can't pick a value for $\sqrt{-1}$ such that every solution is $\pm \sqrt{-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes the equation $a^2=b$ with $b \ge 0$ has always two solution for $b>0$ or one when $b=0$, indicated with $\sqrt b$ and $-\sqrt b$.

For a graphical interpretation, we can consider the equivalent problem for the intersection of  parabola $y=x^2$ with the horizontal line $y=b\ge 0$ which has indeed solutions $x=\pm \sqrt b$.

[image]

---

**Edit**

When $b<0$ we need complex number and notably the imaginary unit defined by $i=\sqrt{-1}$, then we have

$$a^2= b=-1 \cdot (-b) \implies a=\pm i \sqrt {(-b)} $$

For a [quadratic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation) in the form $ax^2+bx+c=0$ or, more in general, for a polynomial equation $p_n(x)=0$ by the [FTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra), we always can find $n$ solutions in the complex field (counted with multiplicity).

Comment: Thank you! Would this hold if we allow complex numbers and allow $b$ to be negative? How about when $a$ and $b$ are expressions, such as if $a = 2x^2+1$ and $b = x$?

Comment: I add something on that but maybe you should it make more clear in the answer that you are asking also for the case $b<0$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another (in my opinion) interesting approach to your question. However, I'm not sure if you're already familiar with this, so my answer might be underwhelming.

In your question you made it sound like $a$ has exactly *two* square roots if $a^2=b$, namely $\sqrt{b}$ and $-\sqrt{b}$. The following just illustrates that this isn't always the case:

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a [positive semi-definite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_matrix) matrix. Then it can be shown that there exists exactly one other positive semi-definite matrix $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, such that $A=B^2$, i.e. $B$ is a square root of $A$, and often times one writes $B = A^{\frac12}$. For example, you can check that
$$
A := 
\begin{pmatrix}
5&4\\
4&5
\end{pmatrix}
\implies
A^{\frac12}=
\begin{pmatrix}
2&1\\
1&2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and that these matrices are indeed positive semi-definite. Of course, as in the case of real numbers, if $B$ is a root of $A$, then so is $-B$. However, it is possible for matrices to have more than two roots. More so, the identity matrix $I_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$ has infinitely many complex roots, namely for example
$$
I_2 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\
0&1
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1&z\\
0&-1
\end{pmatrix}^2,
$$
for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$. Moreover, there are also matrices that have no roots, such as
$$
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\
0&0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Showing that this matrix indeed has no roots is a nice short exercise.

I hope this was helpful in some way!

Comment: Thank you! While I think it's above an Algebra 1 level, I think it further illustrates the differences in "if $a=b$ then $a+c=b+c$" vs. "if $a^2=b$ then $a=\pm \sqrt{b}$."